# Fuzzy visuals and low fps in games, screen tearing in both games and web browser. Happened after changing up drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, fglrx

This started after tf2 kept crashing upon opening. I assumed I might have had a driver issue and switched over to the proprietary drivers from AMD. The crashes persisted so I switched back to the open source drivers provided by Ubuntu and that's when everything hit the fan.

My games would load up. (I tried this on multiple games) but everything was fuzzy the even the menus had a low frame rate and the screen tearing was atrocious. This issue still happened when using any web browser and just interacting with the desktop. Any help is appreciated.

**System and Drivers**

APU: AMD A8 - 5550m

Open source driver (currently in use): X.Org X server--AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from `xserver-xorg-video-ati`

Proprietary: Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from `fglrx`
Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from `fglrx-updates`

I started with the open source, then switched to the proprietary `fglrx-updates`.

Answer (score 1):

For any one who might come across this in the future, I have solved it.

What I did in the first place was use `fglrx-updates`, without ever using the original `fglrx` driver. Once I switched over I was able to play my games and there is no screen tearing.